# If $\alpha>2$, $\int_{1}^\infty \left(\int_{1}^x \exp(y^\alpha)dy \right)\exp(-x^\alpha) \,dx$ is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\alpha>0$ be positive numbers. I am interested in the following integral:

$I_\alpha=\int_{1}^\infty \left(\int_{1}^x \exp(y^\alpha)dy \right)\exp(-x^\alpha) \,dx$

I know that $I_2$ is infinite. Indeed, for $x>1$,
\begin{align*}
&\int_{1}^x \exp(y^2)dy\ge \frac{1}{x} \int_{1}^x y\exp(y^2)\,dy= \frac{1}{2x} [\exp(x^2)-\exp(1)]
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
I_2 \ge \int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{2x} [\exp(x^2)-\exp(1)] \exp(-x^2)\,dx=\infty.
\end{align*}

If $\alpha>2$, I think $I_\alpha$ is finite. However, I don't have a good idea.
Is there a nice (upper) estimate for  $\int_{1}^x \exp(y^\alpha)\,dy$ ?

Comment: Have you tried $u=y^\alpha$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\int_1^x\exp(y^\alpha)\,dy&=\int_1^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{y^{k\alpha}}{k!}\,dy=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k\alpha+1}-1}{k!(k\alpha+1)}.
\end{align}
Since $k\alpha>k$,
\begin{align}
\int_1^x\exp(y^\alpha)\,dy&\leq\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k\alpha+1}}{k!(k+1)}=x^{1-\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{(k+1)\alpha}}{k!(k+1)}\leq x^{1-\alpha}\exp(x^\alpha).
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
I_\alpha\leq\int_1^\infty x^{1-\alpha}\,dx<\infty.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.  I am sorry for my late reply.

Answer (score 1):

Change order of integration. $I_a=\int\limits_1^\infty exp(y^a)\int\limits_y^\infty exp(-x^a)dx dy$.

Lrt $u=x^a$ or $x=u^{(1/a)}$, so $dx=\frac{1}{a}u^{(1/a)-1}$ and lower limit of inner integral is $y^a$.  The inner integral $=\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{y^a}^\infty exp(-u)u^{(1/a)-1}du\lt\frac{1}{a(y^{a-1})}\int\limits_{y^a}^\infty exp(-u)du$

So $I_a\lt \frac{1}{a}\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{dy}{y^{a-1}}$ finite for $a\gt 2$.

Comment: What is wrong with answer?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. The answer seems good.